# How to get blocks with same heigh in columns?

Tags: block-editor, columns

I put 3 paragraph blocks in a 3 columns block.
I'd like the paragraph to have the same size (and ideally to have the vertically centered). Is there a way to achieve this with Gutenberg?

[image: Here is what I have so far]

I tried using the `diplay:flex` attribute with CSS. But it didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution with flex attributes:

I defined the following CSS rules :

```
.flexColumn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: auto !important;
}

.flexItem {
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

I can now apply `flexColumn` to the columns and `flexItem` to the items that I want to grow to fill the empty space:

[image]

For some items I also need to deal with top/bottom margins (`margin-top:0`)